# Can't override default messages in Play 2.0.4

Tags: internationalization, playframework-2.0, overriding, message, default

I'm overriding the default play messages in a file /conf/messages

```
error.required=Dieses Feld ist erforderlich
```

This works on my local machine, but not an a dev server. I deploy the app via 'play stage' and then sync it.

Answer (score 1):

Save it as `messages.en` or better `messages.de` and switch main language to Deutsch in `application.conf`

Comment: I've already tried it with messages.de, then it doesn't work local and remote. What do you mean with 'switch main language'? I have this entry: application.langs="de,fr,it"

Comment: hmmm it should work... Are other messages translated properly for selected language ? Try to call `play clean-all` and then compile your project from the scratch. check for an [example translations in play-authenticate sample](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/conf) (they works), maybe you missed something?